# Sidebar Menu with HTML anchor in R shiny dashboard

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app wherein I want to navigate to a particular HTML item in the same tab using sidebar menu items.

Instead of using menu items to open a new page I want to use the menu items to navigate down to the dashboard to a particular HTML item.

[Create link to the other part of the Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605185/create-link-to-the-other-part-of-the-shiny-app/28605517#28605517)
This page was useful with how to use HTML anchor and  navigate to other parts of shiny APP. I want to use menuItems to perform this function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create link to the other part of the Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605185/create-link-to-the-other-part-of-the-shiny-app)