# R Shiny - create internal link to another element of my app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a very simple question. I'm trying to create internal links in my shiny app where by clicking on these links a user can go to either a specific (internal) tab, table, or plot located on any page of my app.
It's basically similar to what was asked here:
[Create link to the other part of the Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605185/create-link-to-the-other-part-of-the-shiny-app/28605517#28605517)
but at least on my end the solution offered there doesn't work. I know I'm supposed to provide a code snippet but the code is basically the same as the one available on that page.
Another solution I found is the following:
[Linking to a tab or panel of a shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315485/linking-to-a-tab-or-panel-of-a-shiny-app)
but it's dated 2015 and it doesn't link specifically to tables and plots.
I wonder if there's something more recent that I'm missing out.
My ultimate goal is the following: have a main page being like a glossary with links to all the different tabs, tables, and plots available in the app.
Many thanks.

Comment: A `navlistPanel` is like a `tabsetPanel` but with a left-hand ~table of contents rather than tabs at the top. This isn't exactly what you're asking for, but it's an alternative to consider if you don't find what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but to be honest it doesn't help me much.